# Stuck on Boot Animation

Tags: root-access, custom-roms, miui

Recently I installed MIUI v5 rom on my smartphone.

When I rebooted my smartphone it got stuck on the MI Boot Animation Logo.

What is the problem?

Please Help me.

Comment: Can you still boot to recovery or [safe-mode](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/safe-mode/info)? Have you wiped your phone prior to flashing (assuming you've had a different ROM in use before)?

Comment: Did you wipe **dalvik-cache** and **cache** after flashing MIUI? And again after GApps?

Comment: Note that the first boot after flashing a new ROM can take some time.  For anyone reading this, make sure to **wait at least 10 minutes** before jumping to the conclusion that you've soft-bricked your device.

Comment: This is what happened to me and after 8 hours it was still stuck playing the boot animation.  I went into recovery and it told me it couldn't mount `/cache` so I wiped the cache partition, then it booted and asked for a password and complained it couldn't decrypt my data so I did a factory reset (which wipes the user partition), and after that I left it at the boot animation again and after five minutes it finished booting.  This was with the stock ROM.

Answer (score 5):

It is stucked in boot-loop and maybe soft bricked. Its not bricked but can be soft bricked. I had also suffered this problem two times. Dont fear it will not damage any of your hardware function. It only happens if
1. The ROM you flashed doesn't matched with your phone.
2. Gapps has not been installed correctly.

You can solve this problem. Try turning off your phone and after turning on immedietly press the volume up and power button simultaneously. It could be different because different companies have different methods of booting into recovery. If you succeed in it then go ahead and if you fail then try other button combinations. After booting into recovery, navigate to wipe data section by using the volume keys. Then clear your cache partition. After doing this, get your default ROM from any website. I am sure that one or more websites will surely contain  it. AFTER DOWNLOADING IT INSTALL THE ROM. Then clear the dalvik cache and cache. Now, just reboot. Your problem will be solved.If any problem, please comment.

Comment: You forgot to mention to clear `dalvik-cache` and `cache` AFTER flashing ROM and GApps package.

Comment: The OP said "it got stuck on the MI Boot Animation Logo" - I thought a boot loop was when it kept booting, in which case the screen would repeatedly go black and then back to the boot logo, not just stay stuck on the boot logo, right?

Answer (score 1):

This means you are stuck in a bootloop which means that your phone can't boot. It can be caused by the wrong installation of the rom. You can try to do a factory reset from recovery. If it doesn't fix you should try to install the stock rom. If you need more help please ask.

Comment: How can I fix this 'Bootloop' or 'Boot Animation' problem? I know how to install the stock rom and after this problem i successfully  installed the stock rom.